# SQL and equality constraints

Tags: sql, equality, create-table

I am new to ORM modelling and SQL.

I have two tables tableA and tableB, and an equality constraint between two columns, one in each table, tableA.column = tableB.column.

How do I make sure that the content of these columns are equal at all times?

Comment: This is called a foreign key. Please read the manual of your DBMS (which you failed to mention. What _are_ you using? Postgres? Oracle?)

Comment: Look also **[`Referential integrity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..i see postgres and oracle are your favorites :)